# How do I add a listener to editor tab closing in Eclipse RCP 3?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add a listener to closing an editor tab in an eclipse RCP application (I'm using Eclipse RCP 3, not the latest version). I tried overriding the `close()` method from `org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor` (the superclass of my editor), but it isn't called when the tab is closed by the user (using the x button on the right side of the tab header). How can I approach this problem in a different way?

Comment: Use an `IPartListener` to listen for all part changes.

Comment: ... or override the `dispose()` method of your editor.

Comment: Thank you, mr Herrmann, this seems very suitable for me.